# Google Maps - Store Locator - Multiple Filters - Database vs Client Side

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to figure out  a way to filter database.  My problem is that I can easily filter DB by one category. Click a button, and an onclick function will Select * from Database where 1.

Than let’s suppose that I would like to have second and third and fourth layer of filters (and so forth) .

We have already a map based  on the first filter with "x" markers on the screen.

If we create a second filter with a second function, than we are querying the database again (and losing the first round of filtration). This is not what a user would have in his mind. (example: first filter all restaurants in Sacramento. Second filter: Mexican food. You could force the user to check ALL options (filters) first, but this is not user friendly.  People may want to see ALL restaurants, then Mexican and American, and lastly price tag under 20 bucks. Or all restaurants under $10. American bar under $20 and so forth.  Different "store" locators could have 20 levels of filters or more.

I have no idea how to query the screen because in this route you would be already querying the first round of  filters. And then again until user is satisfied.
Any idea on how to do this? Any real example?

Google Maps tutorials always refer to [Ace store locator](http://www.acehardware.com/mystore/storeLocator.jsp). But I can’t understand what they did. I have already spent months in this problem. I am new to computer programming. At least now I know how to put my question into words. Sometimes we have problems in computers  that we can't even find the right words.......

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS There are tons of questions with the same problem, tons of store locator tutorials in the web with input for location and radius. I probably have seen them all. I am trying to add to that.

Answer (score 0):

Send/store your filters on client side too, this way when you add another filter you can send the existing filters back to the server. Usually I have a json object/php array for this that I send along with each request and update it with every filter.

Comment: You are probably right. However, I am so new to this that I can't really understand or turn this part into code: "Send/store your filters on client side too". How do you do that? Sorry about my ignorance.